# Ensure two random shapes are never near each other or overlapping

Tags: c#, wpf, random, position, shapes

```
var random = new Random();
        Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, random.Next((int)(ImageCanvas.Width - 100)));
        Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, random.Next((int)(ImageCanvas.Height - 100)));
        return rectangle;
```

So the above code just randomly sets the Top and Left positions of a rectangle that will appear on the canvas. I can easily reuse this code if I want multiple rectangles to appear on the screen, however what I was having trouble doing is tweaking the code so that each rectangle is never overlapping each other.

I thought of maybe doing a while loop that keeps running random.Next((int)(ImageCanvas.Height - 100)) continuously until it is not equal to the previous random... But that isn't perfect. The shapes are quite big, so having slightly different X or Y coordinates doesn't prevent a overlap. They would somehow need to be at least 50 pixels distance between each other or something for this to prevent any overlap between other rectangles.

Comment: How much of the canvas will eventually be filled, in percents?

Comment: Not much, there will most likely be 2-4 shapes max. So let's say 10-20%?

Comment: Then it will be fine if you check for collision after generating the randoms, and if there is a collision just generate new randoms instead. You can find the logic to check collision between rectangles easily on Google or SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Canvas` is reasonably large, i.e. the rectangles will not occupy a large amount of the area, it most likely suffices to simply generate rectangles at random (as in your example code), and then check to make sure they don't overlap with any of the previously selected rectangles.

Note that "overlaps with another rectangle" is really the same as "has a non-empty intersection with another rectangle". And .NET provides that functionality; for WPF, you should use the `System.Windows.Rect` struct. It even has an `IntersectsWith()` method, giving the information you need in a single call (otherwise you'd have to get the intersection as one step, and then check to see if the result is empty in a second step).

The whole thing might look something like this:

```
List<Rectangle> GenerateRectangles(Canvas canvas, int count, Size size)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    List<Rect> rectangles = new List<Rect>(count);

    while (count-- > 0)
    {
        Rect rect;

        do
        {
            rect = new Rect(random.Next((int)(canvas.Width - size.Width),
                (int)(canvas.Height - size.Height), size.Width, size.Height);
        } while (rectangles.Any(r => r.IntersectsWith(rect));

        rectangles.Add(rect);
    }

    return rectangles.Select(r =>
         {
             Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

             rectangle.Width = r.Width;
             rectangle.Height = r.Height;
             canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, r.Left);
             canvas.SetTop(rectangle, r.Top);

             return rectangle;
         }).ToList();
}
```

You would want something more sophisticated if you were dealing with a more constrained area and/or a larger number of rectangles. The above won't scale well for large numbers of rectangles, especially if the probability of a collision is high. But for your stated goals, it should work fine.

Comment: I've been avoiding System.Drawing because so far I've been using System.Windows.Media.Imaging for stuff like ImageBrushes. The last time I tried to use System.Drawing my code started complaining about conflicting references etc... Does this mean I just have no choice but to avoid using Intersect?

Comment: @JimmyK: none of the above uses System.Drawing. It's entirely WPF/XAML-based. See [`System.Windows.Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`System.Windows.Size`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Strange, I just noticed that. I'm currently using System.Windows, however I can't use System.Windows.Rect. I just spent the last 10 mins browsing for .Rect in my references and just can't find it. Am I wrong in assuming I need to reference System.Windows.Rect? I am currently able to use Rect's so I'd assume there is no need to as long as I have System.Windows. The moment I use .IntersectsWith however, I always get the error "Cannot resolve System 'IntersectsWith' " which makes me think I am missing a reference. It seems like I'm missing something quite obvious and silly here

Comment: @JimmyK: the type is included in the `WindowsBase.dll` assembly. Have you included that in your project references? Also, please make sure you have not aliased the type name `Rect` as some other type (such as `System.Drawing.Rectangle`). You should not need `System.Drawing.dll` at all. When you place the mouse cursor over the type name `Rect` in your code, what is the fully-qualified name that VS displays to you?

Comment: Ah WindowsBase.dll was the issue. Thank you! One issue however, I need to make use of Fill which doesn't seem possible with Rect. Is there anything I can do to get around this?

Comment: @JimmyK: the above code only uses `Rect` for the positioning. Note that at the end, a `Rectangle` object is instantiated for the caller. You can set your `Fill` there, along with any other properties you need.